# Autofitting Content in Outlook through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am automating an email wherein I am copying a range (consisting of words and numbers) from Excel to Outlook. However, whenever I paste the range to outlook, the content is not properly formatted - I would like for the content to be autofitted to the content. Is there a way to do so?

I have tried making the range into a table and deleting the header wherein I would have the data formatted, but ideally, I would like to copy the range over to outlook and then autofit the range from within outlook.

I am using the code from Youtuber Sigma Coding - Please see below for their code

```
Sub RangeToOutlook_Single()

    'Declare Outlook Variables
    Dim oLookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oLookItm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oLookIns As Outlook.Inspector
    
    'Declare Word Variables
    Dim oWrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWrdRng As Word.Range
    
    'Delcare Excel Variables
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Get the Active instance of Outlook if there is one
    Set oLookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
        'If Outlook isn't open then create a new instance of Outlook
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
        
            'Clear Error
            Err.Clear
        
            'Create a new instance of Outlook
            Set oLookApp = New Outlook.Application
            
        End If
        
    'Create a new email
    Set oLookItm = oLookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
          
    'Create an array to hold ranges
    Set ExcRng = Sheet1.Range("B2:C7")

    With oLookItm
    
        'Define some basic info of our email
        .To = "xyz@abc.com"
        .CC = "xyz@abc.com"
        .Subject = "Here are all of my Ranges"
        .Body = "Here are all the Ranges from my worksheet."
        
        'Display the email
        .Display
        
        'Get the Active Inspector
        Set oLookIns = .GetInspector
        
        'Get the document within the inspector
        Set oWrdDoc = oLookIns.WordEditor

        
        ExcRng.Copy
        
        'Define the range, insert a blank line, collapse the selection.
        Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
            oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            
        'Add a new paragragp and then a break
        Set oWrdRng = oWdEditor.Paragraphs.Add
            oWrdRng.InsertBreak
                    
        'Paste the object.
        oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture

    
    End With
        
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code you're using?  Should we guess?

Comment: Please see above now

Comment: Would help to show "as is" and "what I want" screenshots - we can't really know what the exact issue is otherwise.

Comment: Your code inserts the range as an image, so what type of formatting do you want to be able to apply?

Comment: I changed the last line oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
to oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:= wdPasteHTML ... This makes the data output as text wherein I want to be able to autofit the content within Outlook - this will make the data look neater

Comment: If I use `wdPasteHTML` then the column widths already autofit after pasting ...

Comment: I got it to work once I fixed the formatting of my data within Excel itself. Thank you for your help!